# Convert Unicode to UTF-8 Python

Tags: python, database, unicode, utf-8

I am working with a database that has throughout it scattered characters like this: â€™. I need to take this from the database, convert it to UTF-8, and then import it into a different database, using python. When printed to the Windows Command Prompt, these characters look like this: \xe2\u20ac\u2122. I have tried various combinations of .decode(), .encode(), and unicode() to convert the data, but Im really stuck.

Comment: Well, what is the database encoding? UTF-16?

Comment: The database encoding is UTF_8_bin

Comment: Did you try `blah.decode('utf-8-sig')`? What happens when you do?

Comment: The Windows command-prompt cannot display UTF-8 as it uses Win-1252 (a variant of ISO-8859-1).  What you see is the result of trying to display UTF-8 in a non-UTF-8 environment.  Why is the display of the data in a command-prompt important?

Comment: To display properly at the prompt you might want to try putty and connect to localhost, putty supports UTF-8 under the Windows->Translation option. Although I've personally had little luck with this feature.

Comment: The command prompt display is irrelevant, I just thought it might help answer the question. blah.decode('utf-8-sig') doesnt fix the problem. Maybe I need to clarify: I want the final result displayed on a webpage to be a real character, not a â€™.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always *decode* on input, and *encode* on output. (There ought to be handy mnemonic for this: perhaps "*take your code [coat] off when you come indoors*".)

Decode on input: You say that the database encoding is "UTF_8_bin". Are you using [MySQL-Python](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)? If so, then you can set the `use_unicode` option when you connect to the database. Then all strings are fetched from the database in Unicode, so you don't have worry about decoding them.

Encode on output: You can find out the current character encoding (or "[code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)" as they call it in Windows) with the `chcp` command. Let's suppose it's [code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Then you can write

```
print text.encode('windows-1252')
```

to produce something that you can read from the Windows command line.

If you're writing the strings back to another MySQL database using MySQL-Python, you shouldn't need to do anything special: MySQL-Python claims that "you can always write Unicode strings" (regardless of whether you specified `use_unicode` when you opened the connection).

Comment: Where exactly would I specify the use_unicode option? I am running a standalone script on a django app; Do I add this to the settings.py file, or somewhere else?

Comment: It's an option to [`MySQLdb.connect`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes). I don't know anything about Django, but [the documentation suggests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database) that you could put it under `DATABASES.default.OPTIONS` in your configuration.

Comment: DIEO (read as "die-oh")? Despise incompetent, evil offenders? (I'm not very creative. lol)