# Converting Unicode to in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Unicode to UTF-8 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740865/convert-unicode-to-utf-8-python)

I'm a very new python programmer, working on my first script. the script pulls in text from a plist string, then does some things to it, then packages it up as an HTML email.

from a few of the entries, I'm getting the dreaded Unicode "outside ordinal 128" error.

Having read as much as I can find about encoding, and decoding, I know that it is important for me to get the encoded, but I'm having a difficult time understanding when or how exactly to do this.

The offending variable is first pulled in using plistlib, and converted to HTML from markdown, like this:

```
entry = result['Entry Text']
donotecontent = markdown2.markdown(entry)
```

Later, it is put in the email like this:

```
html = donotecontent + '<br /><br />' + var3
part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
```

My question is, what is the best way for me to make sure that Unicode characters in this content doesn't cause this to throw an error. I prefer not to ignore the characters.

Comment: Then, best way to avoid Unicode errors in this content?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339955/python-string-encode-decode

Comment: In general, you want to decode the data into Unicode as early as possible and then encode at the end. I'm not sure of the various parts in your program, but if `entry` is what contains the text, try `entry = result['Entry Text'].decode('utf8')` to get it into Unicode, and then when you are reading to write, perhaps `donotecontent.encode('utf8')`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson No it's not. Unicode and UTF-8 are completely different things. UTF-8 is a coding format for Unicode, is what you use to represent a unicode string as a string of bytes.

Comment: @ManuelCeron that's what I meant. :/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this tomorrow. But, just as a matter of understanding, is it typical to do this with all strings (let's say you're importing a lot of info from a lot of different places and assigning them to variables) or only those strings that are likely to include odd or foreign characters? I'd just like to know. Thank you.

Comment: @sosukeinu: Here are three articles you may find useful: [The Absolute Minimum [one] Must Know...](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: There's a lot of English data out there with Unicode quotes, dashes and accents. Any data you input may have non-ASCII characters in there, and the day you assume there's not, someone will prove you wrong and probably get very upset about it.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for my broken english. I am speaking Chinese/Japanese, and using CJK characters everyday.
Ceron solved almost of this problem, thus I won't talk about how to use `encode()`/`decode()` again.

When we use `str()` to cast any unicode object, it will encode unicode string to bytedata; when we use `unicode()` to cast `str` object, it will decode bytedata to unicode character.

And, the encoding must be what returned from `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

In default, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` return 'ascii' by default, the encoding/decoding exception may be thrown when doing `str()`/`unicode()` casting.

If you want to do str <-> unicode conversion by `str()` or `unicode()`, and also, implicity encoding/decoding with 'utf-8', you can execute the following statement:

```
import sys    # sys.setdefaultencoding is cancelled by site.py
reload(sys)    # to re-enable sys.setdefaultencoding()
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

and it will cause later execution of `str()` and `unicode()` convert any basestring object with encoding utf-8.

However, I would prefer to use `encode()`/`decode()` explicitly, because it makes code maintenance easier for me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using Python 2.x, remember: there are two types of strings: `str` and `unicode`. `str` are byte strings, whereas `unicode` are unicode strings. `unicode` strings can be used to represent text in any language, but to store text in a computer or to send it via email, you need to represent that text using bytes. To represent text using bytes, you need an coding format. There are many coding formats, Python uses *ascii* by default, but *ascii* can only represent a few characters, mostly english letters. If you try to encode a text with other letters using *ascii*, you will get the famous "outside ordinal 128". For example:

```
>>> u'Cerón'.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 3:
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

The same happens if you use `str(u'Cerón')`, because Python uses *ascii* by default to convert `unicode` to `str`.

To make this work, you have to use a different coding format. *UTF-8* is a coding format that can express any unicode text as bytes. To convert the `u'Cerón'` unicode string to bytes you have to use:

```
>>> u'Cerón'.encode('utf-8')
'Cer\xc3\xb3n'
```

No errors this time.

Now, back to your email problem. I can see that you're using `MIMEText`, which accepts an already encoded `str` argument, in your case is the `html` variable. `MIMEText` also accepts an argument specifying what kind of encoding is being used. So, in your case, if `html` is a unicode string, you have to encode it as `utf-8` and pass the charset parameter too (because `HTMLText` uses ascii by default):

```
part1 = MIMEText(html.encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'utf-8')
```

But be careful, because if `html` is already a `str` instead of `unicode`, then the encoding will fail. This is one of the problems of Python 2.x, it allows you to encode an already encoded string but it throws an error.

Another problem to add to the list is that *utf-8* is compatible with *ascii* characters, and Python will always try to automatically encode/decode strings using *ascii*. If you're not properly encoding your strings, but you only use *ascii* characters, things will work fine. However, if for some reason some *non-ascii* characters slips into your message, you will get the error, this makes errors harder to detect.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: You can't decode a unicode, and you can't encode a str

```
>>> u"\xa0".decode("ascii", "ignore")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    u"\xa0".decode("ascii", "ignore")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)


>>> "\xc2".encode("ascii", "ignore")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    "\xc2".encode("ascii", "ignore")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Checkout this excellent [tutorial](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)