# join three strings into one block using python

Tags: python

I have three strings. Each string has names, adresses and postal code.

First string:

```
Joao Miesler
Bill Gates
Kevin Mitnick
```

Second string:

```
Street kit number 3
Street foo number 2
Street OOk number 4
```

Third string:

```
2415-568
1452-856
1234-568
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
Joao Miesler
Street kit number 3
2415-568

Bill Gates
Street foo number 2
1452-856

Kevin Mitnick
Street OOk number 4
1234-568
```

This information was extracted from an excell worksheet like this:

```
#Get columns name
for i in range(13, high_row, 1):
    nome = sheet['E%s' % i].value


#Get column adresses
for i in range(13, high_row, 1):
    morada = sheet['F%s' % i].value

#Get Postal Code column
for i in range(13, high_row, 1):
    cp = sheet['G%s' % i].value
```

Can you point me in the right direction? Some light at the end of the tunnel would be nice.

After this I would like to make an A4 paper and divide the output into squares. Any good library I can use to make it happen?

Comment: Try getting all those values in same `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have three loops when you could just have one?

```
for i in range(13, high_row, 1):
    nome = sheet['E%s' % i].value
    morada = sheet['F%s' % i].value
    cp = sheet['G%s' % i].value

    data = [nome, morada, cp]
    print('\n'.join(map(str,data)))
```

Comment: it did exactly what I wanted. I just had one problem: enconding. I followed this link [Converting Unicode to in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485546/converting-unicode-to-in-python) but charecters like `º` or `ç` are getting weird symbols. Do you have any light at the end of the tunnel for me?

Comment: Hmm, sorry I don't. It could just be a matter of where you are printing the characters. Some terminals allow you to change the encoding settings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in multi-line strings:

```
names = """Joao Miesler
Bill Gates
Kevin Mitnick"""
```

the Pythonic way to do this is to operate on lists of lines and join them using `zip`:

```
names = names.split('\n')
addresses = addresses.split('\n')
phone_numbers = phone_numbers.split('\n')

for name, address, phone in zip(names, addresses, phone_numbers):
   print('%s\n%s\n%s\n' % (name, address, phone))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use lists to store each line of the 3 strings either separately or together the you can choose which lines to print with basic list functionality.

So it would look like:

```
list1 = ['Joao Miesler', 'Bill Gates', 'Kevin Mitnick']
list2 = ['Street kit number 3', 'Street foo number 2', 'Street OOk number 4']
list3 = ['2415-568', '1452-856', '1234-568']

print(list1[0],\n,list2[0],\n,list3[0])
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are multi line strings divided by `\n` and all have the same length

```
s1a = s1.split('\n')
s2a = s2.split('\n')
s3a = s3.split('\n')

newString = '' 
for i in range(len(s1a)):
    newString += (s1a[i]+'\n')
    newString += (s2a[i]+'\n')
    newString += (s3a[i]+'\n')
    newString += '\n'
```