# python list convert to a table

Tags: python, list

I have a list `abc` as below. I would like to convert it to a table as I need to write this data to a file (CSV or any other delimiter) and then open that file in Excel.

The columns in that table will be `company, source, time, link, title` and for the first element in the list, the first row will have values -

```
intel corporation, 
Motely Fool, 
4 hours ago,
http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/05/09/intel-corporations-strange-choice.aspx,
Intel Corporation's Strange Choice
```

How could I achieve the same? `abc` has thousands of elements

```
abc=[{'intel corporation': {'source': u'Motley Fool', 'time': u'4 hours ago', 'link': u'http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/05/09/intel-corporations-strange-choice.aspx', 'title': u"Intel Corporation's Strange Choice"}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Seeking Alpha', 'time': u'33 minutes ago', 'link': u'http://seekingalpha.com/article/3973271-intels-augmented-reality-plans-coming-focus', 'title': u"Intel's Augmented Reality Plans Are Coming Into Focus"}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Seeking Alpha', 'time': u'7 hours ago', 'link': u'http://seekingalpha.com/article/3973098-intel-consider-debt-large-buyback', 'title': u'Should Intel Consider More Debt For A Large Buyback?'}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Schaeffers Research (blog)', 'time': u'9 hours ago', 'link': u'http://www.schaeffersresearch.com/content/news/2016/05/09/analyst-downgrades-apple-inc-berkshire-hathaway-inc-and-intel-corporation', 'title': u'Analyst Downgrades: Apple Inc., Berkshire Hathaway Inc., and Intel ...'}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Money News (press release)', 'time': u'Money News (press release)-12 hours ago Explore in depth (11 more articles)', 'link': u'http://www.newsismoney.com/2016/05/09/shares-of-tech-companies-intel-corporation-nasdaqintc-microsoft-corporation-nasdaqmsft-news-update/', 'title': u'Shares of Tech Companies Intel Corporation (NASDAQ:INTC ...'}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Motley Fool', 'time': u'May 6, 2016', 'link': u'http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/05/06/why-intel-corporation-quit-smartphones-to-focus-on.aspx', 'title': u'Why Intel Corporation Quit Smartphones to Focus on 5G'}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Motley Fool', 'time': u'May 6, 2016', 'link': u'http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/05/06/dont-blame-x86-for-intel-corporations-smartphone-f.aspx', 'title': u"Don't Blame X86 for Intel Corporation's Smartphone Failure"}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Street Updates', 'time': u'11 hours ago', 'link': u'http://www.streetupdates.com/2016/05/09/valuable-analysts-trends-to-observe-intel-corporation-nasdaqintc-taiwan-semiconductor-manufacturing-company-ltd-nysetsm/', 'title': u'Valuable Analysts Trends to Observe: Intel Corporation (NASDAQ ...'}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Motley Fool', 'time': u'May 5, 2016', 'link': u'http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/05/05/intel-corporation-its-time-to-replace-ceo-brian-kr.aspx', 'title': u"Intel Corporation: It's Time to Replace CEO Brian Krzanich"}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Amigobulls', 'time': u'Amigobulls-May 5, 2016 Explore in depth (10 more articles)', 'link': u'http://amigobulls.com/articles/intel-corporations-mobile-exit-could-drive-long-term-gains', 'title': u"Intel Corporation's Mobile Exit Could Drive Long-Term Gains"}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'Seneca Globe', 'time': u'7 hours ago', 'link': u'http://www.senecaglobe.com/intel-corporation-nasdaqintc-not-great-time-continues-downward-trend-trina-solar-nysetsl/323986/', 'title': u'Intel Corporation (NASDAQ:INTC) Has Not Been Having A Great ...'}}, {'intel corporation': {'source': u'The News Journal', 'time': u'19 minutes ago', 'link': u'http://news4j.com/ruling-stocks-in-todays-market-intel-corporation-nasdaqintc-5/', 'title': u"Ruling stocks in today's market: Intel Corporation (NASDAQ:INTC)"}}]
```

Comment: csv or any format table that i can open in excel

Comment: `Pandas` is a very useful library for this kind of work, but it's difficult to answer without additional info. In particular, it has great I/O methods to get a data frame into csv and many other formats (all easily named as in `.to_csv`). How does your data look to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import csv
import sys    # sys.setdefaultencoding is cancelled by site.py
reload(sys)    # to re-enable sys.setdefaultencoding()
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

with open('data.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, ['company', 'source', 'time', 'link', 'title'])
    writer.writeheader()

    for thing in abc:
        for company, details in thing.items():
            details['company'] = company
            writer.writerow(details)
```

Comment: any idea why I am getting alternate blank rows? Also I got `UnicodeEncodeError` `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128) ` Any idea how I could resolve it? - I have multiple values for company name such as "intel corporation", "intel corporation10", "intel corporation20", "intel corporation30" etc

Comment: I changed Alex's code for the file to 'wb' that will handle the alternating blank rows.  You have a unicode problem and that is why you have the ascii issue - there are some q&as here on that issue

Comment: i need help only with alternate blank rows. I was able to resolve other error issues using `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485546/converting-unicode-to-in-python`

Comment: Please add `import sys    # sys.setdefaultencoding is cancelled by site.py`
`reload(sys)    # to re-enable sys.setdefaultencoding()`
`sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` to you import statement as it helps to debug unicode issues and I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: You should accept his answer anyway as it solved the problem you asked about - the encoding issue is a different problem.

Comment: @PyNEwbie I agree. But i want future readers to have the best possible answer. Would it be possible to change `with open('data.csv', 'w')` to `with open('data.csv', 'wb')`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about a table like an excel spreadsheet. If so then you can take a look at the pandas package http://pandas.pydata.org/

After you install the package then you can loop over the items in your list and then iteratively insert them into a Pandas DataFrame(see the pandas link). Also take a look look at [Convert Python dict into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe) it has some info that can help you out.

If you need to you can then export the Dataframe object to .xlsx or csv formats.

Comment: I tried `pd.DataFrame(abc)` but it didnt create a table in the way i want. The table had only one column of name "intel corporation". But I want that to be a column and the only column that the table has needs to be split into 4 different columns

Comment: You need to iteratively add the elements of your list to a dataframe. The pd.DataFrame(abc) works for a dict and not a list. HTH.